# Determine whether ∀ can be factored from an implication

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In other words:

[image]

The answer to this question (I have soln), is no, it cannot be, but when I do my testing, I get true ...

---

Let $X$ represent the set of natural numbers.

Let $p(x)$ - x is $even$

Let $q(x)$ - $x^2$ is $even$

---

On the left hand side, we have:

For all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, x is even $\to$ $x^2$ is even. This is True.

---

On the right hand side, we have:

For all $x \in \mathbb{N},$ x is even $\to$ for all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, $x^2$ is even

We know that $x \in \mathbb{N},$ x is even is False, because this is not the case. Numbers alternate odd to even.

Thus, $x \in \mathbb{N},$ $x^2$ is even is also False, since this is not the case.

So on the left hand side, we have $F \to F$ = T.

---

Overall, we have:

$T \iff T$, which is $T$.

---

My textbook says it is $F$ however. Where is the mistake?

Comment: For one thing, in "$(\forall x, p(x))\to (\forall x, q(x))$", the first $x$ and the second $x$ are not the same $x$. In fact, what you wrote is an abuse of notation which should have been written as  "$(\forall x, p(x))\to (\forall y, q(y))$". Quantifiers "specify a variable" which is "valid" only as long as said quantifier is.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli This is in no way an abuse of notation.  You may argue that it is confusing, but it is completely valid.  In fact, the potentially even more confusing formula "$\forall x.(\forall x.p(x)) \to q(x)$" is completely valid and equivalent to both examples you provide.

Comment: @DerekElkins Not quite. I suppose you meant $\forall x(\forall x(p(x))) \to\forall x(q(x))$, otherwise, I might disagree with you.

Comment: @GitGud I meant what I said. Note, what I wrote is syntactically equivalent to $\forall x.((\forall x.p(x)) \to q(x))$.  That is, the outer forall scopes over the entire remainder of the formula. Your formula is also logically equivalent.  The transformation I used is a general equivalence that holds constructively and holds classically even when the domain is empty.

Comment: @DerekElkins "That is, the outer forall scopes over the entire remainder of the formula". This isn't true, the $q(x)$ bit is unbound in your first comment.

Comment: @GitGud Typically, the "." in $\forall x.P$ means that the scope extends all the way to the right until a closing parenthesis or the end of the term. Either way, I was *stating* what my formula meant. There are a [whole slew of notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantification_(logic)#Notation). Personally, I always use the "." as a) it's the most common form in the contexts I work in, b) I rarely use unbounded quantifiers and $\forall x:\mathbb{N}p(x)$ looks terrible, and c) it allows multiple variables to be nicely quantified $\forall xyz.P$ and generally requires fewer parentheses.

Comment: @DerekElkins If that's the case, then it's all good. I, however, have never seen "." actually being part of the definition of statements, I've only seen it used in informal settings. Can you please point me towards any source that uses "." formally? Thanks.

Comment: @GitGud It's exactly the same as how the "." is commonly used in the [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Notation), and indeed it is used in the same way for $\forall$ in theoretical works on [typed lambda calculi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F) and [programming](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/pubs/qualmlpoly.pdf) [languages](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/crusso/qml/), and *in* programming languages such as [Haskell](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#declaration-type-signatures).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

$X=\mathbb{N}$, $p(x)$ is "$x$ is even", $q(x)$ is "$x^2$ is odd."

Then $\forall x\in X, p(x)$ is false. Thus $(\forall x \in X, p(x)) \Rightarrow (\forall x \in X, q(x))$ is true. However, $\forall x \in X, (p(x) \Rightarrow q(x))$ is false because, for instance, $p(2)$ is true but $q(2)$ is false.

The mistake in your reasoning is that you tried to verify the statement using one particular model. But it does not hold in *all* models, so it is not true.

Comment: So the we have $$F \iff T$$. Which means $F \to T = T$, but $T \to F = F$. So overall, the statement is False?

Comment: That is correct.